# Execute requests not triggered from ExactTarget Journey Builder with Data Bindings

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, databinding

We can use [Data-Bindings](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48357/passing-filter-criteria-from-a-trigger-to-a-custom-activity-in-exacttarget-journ/48458#48458) when execute method is used. But we don't have it after activation of interaction. Here are the steps we are using:

1. Create new interaction in Journey Builder
2. Create new trigger in Journey Builder (using Data Extension)
3. Set Custom Activity (using legacy platform) and configure in Journey Builder
4. Activate Interaction
5. Go to Automation Studio
6. Create a new scheduled automation
7. Drag "Fire Event" and choose Data Extension from step 2
8. Save and run once (result: automation completes without error)
9. Go to the Interaction

We don't have execute request at any of the steps. We need to know when exactly execute request is posted.

As we understand Data Binding is defined by this part of config.json

```
"arguments": {
    "execute": {
       "uri": "https://application.com/api/execute",
       "inArguments": ["{{Event.email}}"],
       "outArguments": [],
       "verb": "POST",
       "body": "",
       "format": "json",
       "useJwt": false,
       "timeout": 10000
    }
}
```

According to [Anatomy of a Custom Activity](http://code.exacttarget.com/assets/images/journey-builder/custom-activity-anatomy.jpg) when interaction is running Journey Builder sends post request to `config.execute.uri`. But it doesn't happen. Save, validate and publish requests are sends.

Please can you confirm this workflow is correct and know how it we can know when trigger is launched by Automation Studio (or by REST API through Fire Event).

Answer (score 1):

I think the parameter is 'url' now in config.json, not 'uri'

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and if it works I'll mark your answer as accepted.