# How to use Journey DE data in Custom Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity, databinding

We have created a custom activity that successfully sends a POST call to the relevant endpoint.
But we can't get it to bind data from the Journey DE.

Have seen this:

```
{{Event.my-custom-product-trigger-key.ProductId}}
```

Here: [Stack Exchange post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48357/passing-filter-criteria-from-a-trigger-to-a-custom-activity-in-exacttarget-journ)

Is that the right approach?
How do I fund the `custom-product-trigger-key`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to find your event definition key inspect journey payload using dev tools of your browser (network tab):

[image]

Once you have **eventDefinitionKey**  (in my example: DEAudience-3ab446ce-0427-deea-6871-033f3327ef9c) your final result will look like:

```
{{Event.DEAudience-3ab446ce-0427-deea-6871-033f3327ef9c.ProductId}}
```

Other approach is to develop something generic, check my example:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/221888/47806

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to get the event definition key dynamically with JS/ AMPscript? so that we aren't bound to the same DE.

Comment: I have shared link to generic solution in my answer, there you can find and extract all event source fields. Also you can try to use requestTriggerEventDefinition or requestInteraction postmonger events to find eventDefinitionKey.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm